# How to script downloading file from remote host

Tags: scripting

In remote server, there are always a pair of files like:-

### in folder /Pair1

`IN_S-WW001_20160418100715.out
 IN_S-WW001_20160418100715.txt`

### in folder /Pair2

`ar.MON.20160226.output.ZZ.out
 ar.MON.20160226.output.ZZ.txt`

This is just an example of files. There will be a lot of them generated in one day.

File name in a pair is always same except for timestamps. From other server, I need to SFTP to the remote server and check one pair by one pair.

Logic: The script should check if .out file is there, then grab/download the .txt file (from the pair). Once the .txt file is transferred/downloaded successfully, script will go back to remote server and delete the .out file.

This is my test script:-

```
lftp sftp://$UserID:$PASSWORD@10.x.x.x -e "ls /home/adm/testfiles|grep .out; bye" >> $LOG
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "Files exist, getting *.txt" >> $LOG
lftp sftp://$UserID:$PASSWORD@10.x.x.x -e "mget /home/adm/testfiles/*.txt -O /home/adm/test/ ; bye" >> $LOG
else
echo ".out files do not exist" >> $LOG
fi
```

The problem is that, it will list out all files with extension .out instead of checking pair by pair. I do not know how to classify a pair. I am not good in scripting, so, I have to ask for some help.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop that loops round the .out files should work. The following is not tested as I'm unfamiliar with lftp and its output.

```
for file in $(lftp sftp://$UserID:$PASSWORD@10.x.x.x -e "ls /home/adm/testfiles|grep .out; bye")
do
  echo "Found .out file: $file"
  TXTFILE=$(echo $file | sed -e 's/.out$/.txt/')
  lftp sftp://$UserID:$PASSWORD@10.x.x.x -e "mget /home/adm/testfiles/$TXTFILE -O /home/adm/test/ ; bye"
  # Do any deleting here
done
```

Comment: Thanks @Unbeliever. You gave me some idea to proceed further